# Creating a FUNCTION in phpmyadmin fails - why?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the SQL I am running. It runs without problems in my local SQL environment.

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddWorkDays
(
    WorkingDays INT,
    StartDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME

BEGIN
DECLARE Count INT;
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE NewDate DATETIME;
SET Count = 0;
SET i = 0;

WHILE (i < WorkingDays) DO
    BEGIN
        SELECT Count + 1 INTO Count;
        SELECT i + 1 INTO i;
        WHILE DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL Count DAY)) IN (1,7) DO
            BEGIN
                SELECT Count + 1 INTO Count;
            END;
        END WHILE;
    END;
END WHILE;

SELECT DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL Count DAY) INTO NewDate;
RETURN NewDate;
```

END;

Running this in phpmyadmin gives me:

> ***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 9***

Line 9 is:

```
DECLARE Count INT;
```

Comment: Did you remember to change the delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be working just fine both in phpmyadmin and MySQLWorkbench or you add the definer...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `AddWorkDays`(
    WorkingDays INT,
    StartDate DATETIME
) 

RETURNS datetime
BEGIN
    DECLARE Count INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE NewDate DATETIME;
    SET Count = 0;
    SET i = 0;

WHILE (i < WorkingDays) DO
    BEGIN
        SELECT Count + 1 INTO Count;
        SELECT i + 1 INTO i;
        WHILE DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL Count DAY)) IN (1,7) DO
            BEGIN
                SELECT Count + 1 INTO Count;
            END;
        END WHILE;
    END;
END WHILE;

SELECT DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL Count DAY) INTO NewDate;
RETURN NewDate;
```

END;